# Can not get mvn workign ont he path

Tags: windows, maven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing maven on windows 7 64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219628/installing-maven-on-windows-7-64bit)

maven works when called directly from the bin directory, but have tried a variety of combinations with windows 7 environment variables, and nothing works.

Hopefully the below screenshot captures everything - the path is set, m2_home is set, mvn works when called directly in the same location as specified on path....

[image: mvn wtf ?]

Comment: I needed to set path to include JAVA_HOME before M2_HOME

Answer (score 1):

you have to remove the space before %M2_HOME% - the windows PATH environment variable does not allow using spaces without getting confused.

Comment: added my comment which answered it for me, spaces work fine btw

Answer (score -1):

Is there a space between `CATALINA_HOME%\bin;` and `M2_HOME\bin` try removing it. BTW what do you get when you echo `PATH`?

Comment: added my comment which answered it for me, spaces work fine btw

Comment: ah! Ya I should have thought of that instead.