# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

May be question is asked before but i found very strange kind of error.
When I run `mvn --version` command from bin its gives the version and the other information. However when I run outside bin it gives exception. Both the result mention below

```
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (r01de14724cdef164cd33c7c8c2fe155faf9602da; 2013-02-19 19:21:
28+0530)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5
Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5>mvn --version
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also i set JAVA_HOME in user variable and M2_HOME, M2 in system environment variable. The output for these variables and `%path%` is:

```
C:\Users\SAHILBHALLA>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

C:\Users\SAHILBHALLA>echo %M2%
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin

C:\Users\SAHILBHALLA>echo %M2_HOME%
C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5

C:\Users\SAHILBHALLA>echo %path% 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPow erShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;.;
```

Tell me where i am wrong. What should i do recover from it?

Comment: Did you place those environment variables to PATH?

Comment: is the location of mvn.exe in your %PATH%? e.g. your second mvn invocation is actually happening one directory UP from where you did the first one, so I'm guessing it's not in the path. try `bin\mvn` as the command instead.

Comment: Marc B if I do `bin\mvn` then i will not able to access from any other location( from my workspace)

Comment: See the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36601957/2114308

Comment: You can consider [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33589226/4575793).
Be aware that (at least for recent Windows) there is a difference between user (above) and system environment variables such as `path`. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHtTQ.png)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

My problem solved, `path` didn't resolve `%M2%`. When i added location of maven-bin in the path instead of `%M2%` after that commands works.

I would like to thanks to all those who try to solve the problem

Comment: the same happened to me and I also had to restart my PC because somehow when I used `echo %PATH%` I kept seeing the old path I don't know why.

Comment: When i added the path this error gone. But when i restart the system it again shows this error. The path is there in environment variables. But i want to delete and set the path again to make it work. Why?

Answer (score 30):

This problem arise because there is no any environmental variable corresponding to installed maven in your OS.
For fixing this problem, I always use Intellij's bundled Maven and do not install separate version of Maven again, for finding bundled Maven's path go to intellij and hit `Ctrl+Alt+S` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Build tool` -> `Maven` -> `Maven home directory` you can find the intellij's bundled maven path there as below image demonstrates.

[image]

Then go to `System environment variables` and set these variables:

> Variable name: MAVEN_HOME
>
> Variable value: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven3

Path update: C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3

[image]

After defining system variable `MAVEN_HOME` find variable `path` and add this line to the list

`%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`

[image]

Work is done, open command prompt and test it by writing `mvn -v`. 99 percent of the time it work, if you're among 1 percent, you have to restart your computer.

If you want to use `mvn` command from intellij's internal terminal you have to restart intellij after setting environment variables, then you shouldn't have any problem running maven command from terminal.

Comment: This did the job for me. Thanks a lot man !

Answer (score 14):

maven should be on the system's `PATH` if you wish to execute it from any place. add `%M2_HOME%\bin` to the `PATH`

Comment: as i mention earlier M2_HoME and M2 set in system environment variable

Comment: right... which is why @radai is having you add %M2_HOME%/bin to %PATH%.  trust me, this will work.

Comment: @thekbb - whenever you type in the name of an executable or shell (bat) file, the operating system looks for it in the current directory youre in. if it doesnt find it there it goes over all of the directories that are mentioned in %PATH%. if you want mvn to be accessible then %M2_HOME%\bin _HAS_ to be on the path. the fact that %M2_HOME% exists is not enough (although that too is needed)

Comment: @rahul but %M2% is not where mvn is located, %M2%\bin is what should be on the path

Comment: M2 already contain bin as echo gives `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.0.5-bin\apache-maven-3.0.5\bin`

Answer (score 10):

First of all make sure you java is working or not run this command in cmd

```
 C:\>java -version
```

if it's working it will show this output:-

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

**step 1.** First set your java_home[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74] path in user variable.

**step 2.** Then set MAVEN_HOME[C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9] path in system variable and make sure your maven folder should be present in C folder only.

**step 3.** Then set M2 path in system variable and give maven bin location there i.e.[C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin].

**Step 4.** Then set new system variable i.e. **variable name** = MAVEN_OPTS in and **variable value** =-Xms256m -Xmx512m

**Step 5.** Then edit path/system path variable be care full don't remove anything from there simply add java_home path i.e=;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74 and M2 variable=;%M2% in the end.

**Step 6.** To make sure maven is now working or not run this command in cmd

```
> C:\>mvn --version
```

if it's working it will show this result :-

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-
7+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_74, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

Answer (score 8):

In Windows 10, I had to run the windows command prompt (cmd) as administrator.
Doing that solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

In windows 7, I Got it resolved after adding the environment variables in system level.
If you do not have enough permission try to set the `%JAVA_HOME%` and the `%M2_HOME%` in System variables instead of User Variables.

Answer (score 4):

Place the full path to `mvn` in your `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

After setting the path with the Maven bin location close the prompt window and restart it. Use the `echo %path%` command to make sure the path is set with Maven variables then run the command `mvn -version`. Somehow if the path is set when the prompt window is running it does not pick the new variables.

Comment: Thanks for contributing an answer to StackOverflow.  To make your answer easier to read, you can put commands you want formatted in monospace font between back ticks such as this `.  I've updates your answer for you to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem please follow the steps below:

1. Download the maven zip file from
   http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
2. Extract the maven zip file
3. Open the environment variable and **in user variable section** click on **new** button and make a variable called **MAVEN_HOME** and assign it the value of bin path of extracted maven zip
4. Now in System Variable click on **Path** and click on **Edit** button --> Now Click on **New** button and paste the **bin** path of maven zip
5. Now click on **OK** button
6. Open **CMD** and type **mvn -version**
7. Installed Maven version will be displayed and your setup is completed

Answer (score 3):

The following helped me in Win10.

- Add `%M3_HOME%\bin;` as value for Path variable under User Variables.
- Add full path to maven binary folder as Variable Value for `M3_HOME` variable under System Variables.
- Add `%M3_HOME%\bin;` as value for Path variable under System Variables.
- Click OK wherever applicable.
- Close the existing command prompt.
- Open new command prompt and navigate to Maven binary folder.
- Type `mvn -version`

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm) is the best Maven-Environment Setup tutorial for Windows, Unix and Mac Operating systems.

But in the last you have to set value of `PATH` variable as `";%M2_HOME%\bin"` instead of `"%M2%"`, because `PATH` variable is not able to reduce the value using "%M2%"

Answer (score 1):

got it solved by first creating new "Path" variable under **User variables** (note that after fresh windows install Path variable is not created as User variable, only as system)
after that, I appended %M2% (pointing to maven dir/bin) to (freshly created) user Path variable. after that restarted cmd window and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the shell (cmd for windows) and set the path variable manually from there. It works often from there. Read more at http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Answer (score 1):

Go to Environment Variable and paste the following:

**Under System Variable:**
**Step 1:**
New --> New User Variable 
1. Variable name: MAVEN_HOME
2. Variable_value : D:\apache-maven-3.5.2

**Step 2:**
1. Go to the path --> and paste this  - %MAVEN_HOME%\bin

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps...

cmd : mvn -version

go apache-maven folder > bin

copy the path and go System properties > environment variables > system variables

> path > edit > [paste the file path]

next restart your machine.

https://youtu.be/RQ_Z859Hd7Q

Answer (score 0):

I prefer adding path to ~/.bashrc.

vim ~/.bashrc, then add these lines:

```
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven-your_maven_path&version
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
```

Comment: I'm sure most of us would prefer adding to .bashrc, but he's clearly on windows so it's unlikely he has bash.

Comment: Sorry didn't pay attention to the OS :P

Answer (score 0):

I did all of this in Windows 10 and still had a problem. In the end it turned out that 
the path to the Maven home folder was not exactly what was expected in many of these answers as it turned out to be /apache-maven-3.6.3-bin/apache-maven-3.6.3. Once I corrected this for both the system variables and the PATH variable, it worked. In short, if you have set the environment variables up as directed and it still won't work, I would double check to make sure the variables really point to the exact path to the Maven home folder and the bin folder on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

i do like this , i use with intellij

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3
```

and you also need to add this in the Path variable

click Path -> Edit -> New -> and paste it so it references to just created

```
%M2_HOME%\bin
```