# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file error in Windows 10

Tags: java, maven

I have read similar questions about this problem but it is not working anyways.

**I've extracted maven 3.3.3 to D:\Maven (Java already installed and works fine) then added 2 system variables:**

| Variable | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `M2` | `%M2_HOME%\bin` |
| `M2_HOME` | `D:\Maven` |

**I've also appended next in the path:**

`%M2%`

But it is still not working.

I can execute `mvn -version` from the `D:\Maven\bin` but can't do this from another directory.

Comment: Please verify inside D:\Maven\bin there is mvn.bat exist or not.

Comment: Make sure you have your maven bin directory in the path and the JAVA_HOME property set

Comment: This is a Windows path issue, not a Maven issue.  What does echo %PATH% return?

Comment: You can consider [this related Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17432809/4575793).
Be aware that (at least for recent Windows) there is a difference between user (above) and system environment variables such as `path`. [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHtTQ.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't put extra space in your path after D:\Maven\bin; in D:\Maven\bin; D:\Program Files\NodeJS; Please don't make any space in path variable.

Normally, To set mvn in command line in windows :

1. Set JAVA_HOME property in system environment
   eg. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`
2. Set M2_HOME property in system environment
   eg. `M2_HOME=D:\apache-maven-3.3.3`
3. Finally add maven to PATH

   `;%M2_HOME%\bin;` add this at the end of PATH property of system environment

Now Try `mvn -version`

Comment: I think your maven is break mvn.bat . just download from this link and do above thing http://www.eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.3.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zip

Comment: What is the result of echo %JAVA_HOME%

Comment: C:\Users\Boris>echo %JAVA_HOME%  D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66  Also reinstalled maven. Still not working.

Comment: do you try by downloading new archive also using above link?

Comment: Yes. Older version is the same but I downloaded by link above anyway.

Comment: Hello here is one extra space in you path after D:\Maven\bin; in D:\Maven\bin; D:\Program Files\NodeJS; please dont make any space in path variable. if it is possible please write whole PATH property here.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Please, update your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Also try mvn -version by opening command as Adminstrator . Otherwise try also maven -version

Comment: Ensure that you start a new cmd prompt when you change the Environment varibale settings because changes are not reflected on the older cmd prompt on which you were working  before doing env variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put full maven path upto bin like "**C:\Users\ABC\Downloads\maven-2.0.5-bin\maven-2.0.5\bin**" directly into path variable of os, then you will be able to understand where problem exists.

Answer (score 0):

One mistake I did was, There will two environment variables section

One can be accessed via admin while the other one doesn't require any.
Please specify the paths in the second place

It will work for sure., also try `echo %M2_HOME%` to check whether you have configured correctly..before jumping to `mvn install`

Hope this helps for someone who has to use admin rights