# mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, maven, cmd, environment-variables

I have created these variables with their respective values, but even after doing this, command prompt is not recognizing `mvn` command

**System Variables:**

- name: `M2_HOME`
- value: `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1`
- name: `M2`
- value: `%M2_HOME%/bin;`
- name: `path`
- value: `%JAVA_HOME%\bin; %M2_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: Have you verified that `mvn.exe` lives inside `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin`?

Comment: You must restart command prompt after aplying changes to system variables.

Comment: @merlin2011: bin folder consist of 2 batch files n some other files as well, but there is no mvn.exe file

Comment: @user11153 sir i have restarted it

Comment: Is one of those files `mvn.bat`?

Comment: Try typing the full name `mvn.bat` instead of just `mvn`? (In the restarted `cmd.exe`.

Comment: @merlin2011 'mvn.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: just do `set path` which outputs the complete `path` and see whether `path` is correctly set.

Comment: Please refer this for above issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219628/installing-maven-on-windows-7-64bit/36601957#36601957

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Maven documentation page](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/windows-prerequisites.html):

> Maven, like many cross-platform tools, can encounter problems when
>   there are **space characters in important pathnames**. The instructions
>   below will remind you of this for several particular items.

You have Maven installed in `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1`

Try to reinstall it to, for example, `C:\maven`, or change your current variable `M2_HOME` to `C:\PROGRA~1\apache-maven-3.2.1`

Comment: Pb pbly come from space indeed, but no need to reinstall just remove the space for the path using system folder names (C:\PROGRA~1\) or surround the path with double quotes

Comment: i have tried double quotes, but the output remains the same

Comment: @Gab Thanks, edited. @user3209819 Try `C:\PROGRA~1\apache-maven-3.2.1`, without quotes

Comment: @Gab thanks a lot sir, it worked, its just the replacement of "Program Files" with "PROGRA~1", but what is the reason ?

Comment: the space character. please accept my answer to close the question; You should also upvote the one above cause the maven doc quote is appropriated

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

What I did to resolve this is creating M2_HOME & MAVEN_HOME.
Also, edit Path variable value.

[image: Created two System variables M2_HOME and MAVEN_HOME]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
New ->*C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin*

where *Apache Software Foundation* is a folder I created to extract the ***apache-maven-3.6.0-bin.zip*** file.

Also, make sure Java is working fine and JAVA_HOME is properly set.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try :

- to restart the command prompt
- to start the command prompt with run/cmd instead of shift+right-click -"*open command window here*"
- to put the system path between double quote to manage espace character
- to replace `C:\Program Files\` per `C:\PROGRA~1\`

**edit**

this is my own config :

```
MAVEN_HOME="C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1"

PATH=XXX;%MAVEN_HOME%\bin;XXX
```

Comment: please see my edit. Could you add the result of `echo %path%` command to your question if it's not fixed yet ?

Comment: the output of echo %path% is:

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin

Comment: if you try to replace the Program Files of jdk path per PROGRA~1 ? Actually your mvn executable seems well added to the path and should be recognized

Answer (score 1):

Hello I had the same problem and I figured it out that I was including some space characters on the "path" next to the ; just by removing the space character I was able to have everything working properly"

Answer (score 0):

this is the settings for my maven.

name: MVN_HOME
value: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1

name: path -> add the following value(just the maven part)
value: %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%MVN_HOME%\bin; -> this should have no spaces

Comment: still no use, i have made these changes but still the same output

Answer (score 0):

I have a very difficult time to solve this problem. It did not work no matter how I set up the environment variables in the control panel of Win7.

My final solution is to set the variables via the cmd.

```
set M2_HOME "D:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.3"
set M2=%M2_HOME%\bin
set path=%path%;%M2%
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo:

change

```
name: M2
value: %M2_HOME%/bin;
```

to

```
name: M2
value: %M2_HOME%\bin;
```

if it doesn't work change %M2_HOME%\bin with the path.
in this case:

C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.2.1\bin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the path under the System Variables and not User Variables.

Comment: No, User variable should work as well. Sometimes it is not possible to set System Variables (e.g. if you don't have Administrator privileges)

Comment: When i had maven only set on the path in user variables it didn't pickup the version. When i added it to system variables instead, it worked for me.

Comment: maybe it worked for you, but probably because of something else. Maybe you logged out or rebooted the system and that's the reason, why this approach worked. Still this does not seem like a good answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, for reasons I cannot explain, it made a difference to windows 7 if the MAVEN_HOME environment variable was defined in "System Variables" vs "User Variables".

I originally had both JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME as "User Variables" and "Java -version" worked but windows could not find mvn (My path variable looked like this in both cases "Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\bin;E:\Clif\Java\apache-maven-3.6.0\bin;")

Once I changed both Environment variables from "User Variables" to "System Variables" windows was able to find mvn.

Answer (score 0):

I was using **`%MAVEN_HOME%`** in the variable **`path`** and it was giving problem, even though **`echo %MAVEN_HOME%`** command was showing the right path.

I changed it to **`C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin`** in the path (Depends on your version of-course) and it worked like a charm.