# mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I followed all the tutorials and tried to use maven.

I run win 7, and downloaded maven 3.5.4.

> 1. I placed the zip file under c:\Maven and extract it in that location.
> 2. I navigate to Environment variables and create Variable M2, and put value %M2_HOME%\bin.
> 3. I navigate to Environment variables and create Variable M2_HOME and put value C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4
> 4. I navigate to System variables and in  Path I added %M2_HOME%\bin
> 5. In System variables the variable JAVA_Home has value C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65

What am I missing?

[[image: maven path]][maven path]

[[image: java path]][java path]

[[image: env variable]][env variable]

[[image: system variable]][system variable]

[[image: java home]][java home]

[[image: echo]][command line]

[[image: maven path]][maven path]

Comment: echo the PATH.It seems there is a space after the semi-colon.

Comment: First only the entry in `PATH` is needed which means `C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin`. Everything else `M2`, `M2_HOME` just remove it...Of course you have to set JAVA_HOME...afterwards. Close the command line box and reopen it and try `mv --version`...

Comment: echo path the first path is the maven path

Answer (score 2):

Resolve this is creating M2_HOME & MAVEN_HOME and editing Path variable. You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55056735/7940315)

Answer (score 1):

When using Windows, I prefer to install with chocolatey.org 
You can put Java, mvn, etc on your machine and forget about it. 
Similar to the package management system in Linux

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I faced, In your screen shot you are missing the `LICENSE`, `NOTICE`, and `README.txt`.

That was because you should unzip and then copy, you would have just copied without unzipping the files.

Make sure you get the `LICENSE` file is in the folder. That resolved this issue.